# How to set ceph dout level?

Tags: c++, distributed-system, ceph, cephfs

I am learning bluestore of ceph. I am trying to use the ceph_object_store to test bluestore. But I see lots of unrelated log output.  But I can't see any output related to the benchmark. I found the benchmark uses dout(0) to print log. So how could I close the unrelated log output and set the benchmark to print?

Those unrelated log output likes:

> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.821+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  1
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin) _upgrade_super from 4, latest
> 4 2021-07-13T08:17:51.821+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  1
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin) _upgrade_super done
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.825+0000 7f9b6cddd700  0 Writing 10 MB in blocks
> of 4 KB 2021-07-13T08:17:51.885+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  0 Wrote 10 MB in
> 64958us, at a rate of 157640 KB/s and 39410 iops
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.889+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  1
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin) umount
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b6d5de700  0
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin)  allocation stats probe 1:
> cnt: 2560 frags: 2560 size: 10485760 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000
> 7f9b6d5de700  0 bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin)  probe -1: 0,
> 0, 0 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b6d5de700  0
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin)  probe -3: 0,  0, 0
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b6d5de700  0
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin)  probe -5: 0,  0, 0
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b6d5de700  0
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin)  probe -9: 0,  0, 0
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b6d5de700  0
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin)  probe -17: 0,  0, 0
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b6d5de700  0
> bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin) ------------
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  4 rocksdb:
> [db/db_impl/db_impl.cc:446] Shutdown: canceling all background work
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  4 rocksdb:
> [db/db_impl/db_impl.cc:625] Shutdown complete
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  1 bluefs umount
> 2021-07-13T08:17:51.897+0000 7f9b76d5f2c0  1 bdev(0x55d2cc098800
> /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin/block) close 2021-07-13T08:17:52.173+0000
> 7f9b76d5f2c0  1 freelist shutdown 2021-07-13T08:17:52.173+0000
> 7f9b76d5f2c0  1 bdev(0x55d2cc098400
> /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-admin/block) close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Ceph subsystem log levels to 0 and just set the log level on the needed subsystem. The full list and how to set is documented here:
https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/troubleshooting/log-and-debug/#ceph-subsystems